# Why is this question whether an interface requires an IP in subnet marked as off-topic

Tags: discussion

I posted this question: [How does routing work in the case sending packets from an interface Where the sender does not have an IP in the subnet](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84018/how-does-routing-work-in-the-case-sending-packets-from-an-interface-where-the-se)

It was marked as off-topic because it has to do with hosts/servers. I disagree with that. This is a basic networking question.

Comment: I really do not see the problem. If you had asked on [su] as suggested, you probably would have an answer by now, but you insist on asking on the incorrect site. Not all network questions are network engineering questions.

Comment: "_This is a basic networking question._" Those are quite often _not_ network engineering questions. Your question is certainly something not done in a "_professionally managed network in a business environment_," as is the purpose of NE as explained in the [tour] and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page.

Answer (score 0):

From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, **Off-Topic** section: "*configuration or operation of hosts/servers/VMs*."

What you are asking depends on the operation of a host OS, which you have not even detailed, and has nothing to do with network engineering. Not all network questions are network engineering questions. As i explained in the comment, you could ask your question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Also, remember that a packet sent to a different network than the source network will be sent at layer-2 to the gateway configured on the host. Routers route layer-3 packets between networks, and a gateway must be on the same network as the host. Layer-3 packets are encapsulated in layer-2 frames to be delivered on the LAN, either to the destination host (destination on the same layer-3 network) or to the gateway configured on the host (destination on a different layer-3 network).

Comment: How exactly is it operating/Host OS dependent whether it's a alllowed for a device to send packets into a subnet it is not a part of?

Comment: Whether you can make it work on some Host is an entirely different question. The question here is whether this is a valid network.

Comment: Please give a good network description or diagram, the on-topic network device models, and the network device configurations. You have none of that because you are connecting two hosts, and you want to know if the hosts can communicate. This is not network engineering, it is how host OSes behave under those circumstances. There are no network devices, and on-topic theory has been explained, but what will actually happen depends on your hosts, not the network.